# How to load a q-img using a relative path from an object?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

My Vue 3 / TypeScript app is using Quasar. I have an object holding the relative path to my images, and I'm trying to use that to load the relative path for a [quasar](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/img#introduction) `q-img`.

Here is the example code:

```TypeScript
<template>
  <q-page class="flex flex-center">
    <q-item-section
      v-for="(plan, index) in plans"
      :key="index"
      :class="plan.class"
      class="col"
    >
      <q-img :src="plan.imageSrc" style="margin: auto; max-width: 64px" />
    </q-item-section>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const plans = [
  {
    imageSrc: "~/src/assets/paper-plane.png",
    monthlyPrice: "699",
    class: "starter",
  },
  {
    imageSrc: "~/src/assets/airport.png",
    monthlyPrice: "2,789",
    class: "growth",
  },
];
</script>
```

It should display the image at the relative path found at `plan.imageSrc` but no images are shown.

And the console also throws these errors:

```TypeScript
http://localhost:8080/~/src/assets/paper-plane.png 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8080/~/src/assets/airport.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Also I tried using `require` as per below, and it also does not work:

```TypeScript
 <q-img :src="require(plan.imageSrc)" style="margin: auto; max-width: 64px" />
```

It throws console errors like this:

```TypeScript
Error: Cannot find module '~/src/assets/paper-plane.png'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to dynamically load assets from `/src/assets` in a `<q-img>` using `import.meta.url`, like explained on https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url

```js
const plans = [
  {
    imageSrc: new URL('../assets/paper-plane.png', import.meta.url).href,
    monthlyPrice: "699",
    class: "starter",
  },
  {
    imageSrc: new URL('../assets/airport.png', import.meta.url).href,
    monthlyPrice: "2,789",
    class: "growth",
  },
];
```

Comment: Yes I can also do that. But try to load the src dynamically from an object. That is where my problem arises.

Comment: Ops, I missed part of the problem. Try with `new URL('../assets/images/login/google-icon.svg', import.meta.url).href` meanwhile I update the answer, seems to work here